# Use AsyncTask in other class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wish to use asynctask in class of its on, the reason is that later on I need to export this class as external jar for that the user can add this to his project and just use it.

```
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        for (int i = 0; i < files; i++) 
        {
            //send file to download
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        //need to send notification to main class

        //pr_bar.setProgress(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    public boolean ftpDownload(String srcFilePath, String desFilePath,  final long size_server) {

                //download file
                publishProgress((int) prog);
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

When the user will use:

```
public class UserClass extends Activity {

String serialnum = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userclass);

         new Download().execute();
}
```

How can the user in his class can get notification about the progress of asynctask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the context of your class via the asynctask constructor. By using that context you can access the display related methods of your class

so in your separate AsyncTask class create a constructor like

```
Context c;
public Download(Context c){
   context  = c;
}
```

and from the main class you can call like

```
 new Download(this).execute();
```

by using the context you can access the public components of your class

Answer (score 0):

Just set `int progress` var in your class and update it when progress and make getter method in your async task class, so user can use getProgress() method to get progress from async task.

or

You can create interface inside your async task which users should implement so that they can get callback on progress of async task.

Comment: I like the second option better.